# How to retrieve matching values from a single column in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following table

```
Id     Avatar
1      Smarty.resident
2      ticklethis.resident
3      Renae resident
4      ticklethis
5      Smarty resident
6      Hirpantemp
7      loveyoubaby
8      Hirpantemp.resident
9      Renae
10     Sweetme
11     ticklethis resident
```

I am unable to write SQL command to get similar Names like following

```
Id     Avatar
1      Smarty.resident
5      Smarty resident
2      ticklethis.resident
4      ticklethis
11     ticklethis resident
3      Renae resident
9      Renae
6      Hirpantemp
8      Hirpantemp.resident
```

Comment: it is html, should be asking for jquery not sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little dubious with the assumptions in replace, but this would probably work for the given dataset:

```
select ID, Avatar
from MyTable
where replace(replace(Avatar, '.resident', ''), ' resident', '') in (
    select replace(replace(Avatar, '.resident', ''), ' resident', '') as Avatar
    from MyTable
    group by replace(replace(Avatar, '.resident', ''), ' resident', '')
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Hey Tim it is working fine. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: This command gives me output without resident. What should I do to maintain the username means how to show data with resident keyword?